# How does DataContractJsonSerializer.ReadObject(XmlReader, Boolean) read json from an XmlReader?

Tags: .net, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm looking at the ms documentation for [DataContractJsonSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.readobject?view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Serialization_Json_DataContractJsonSerializer_ReadObject_System_Xml_XmlReader_) which lists an overload for ReadObject:

```
ReadObject(XmlReader, Boolean)
```

The documentation states:

> Reads an XML document mapped from JSON with an XmlReader and returns
> the deserialized object; it also enables you to specify whether the
> serializer should verify that it is positioned on an appropriate
> element before attempting to deserialize.

What does this mean?  how do you get a json object into an XmlReader?

Comment: You call one of the overloads of [`JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.createjsonreader?view=net-5.0).  [Mapping Between JSON and XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/mapping-between-json-and-xml) explains how JSON is transcoded into XML in runtime for consumption by `DataContractJsonSerializer`.  Is that all you need to answer your question?

Comment: @dbc - yes thanks,  I didn't understand how json mapped into xml actually worked.